# What happens when an Azure Logic App is disabled?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

What happens when an Azure Logic App is disabled?

Does the current *"run"* finish, or is it terminated at whatever action is currently on?

In our case, we have a logic app that has a trigger on a message being added to a Service Bus queue ... *the Logic App is doing a Peek/Lock read of the message*

Various actions, including a SQL Db write, and finishing with a Service Bus complete on the message

If the current run finishes, then we don't have to worry, as that particular message has been "processed"

But if the current run is terminated wherever it is, Service Bus will return the message to the queue after the timeout, and then when the Logic App is re-enabled, we'd re-process the original message from the Service Bus queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current in flight runs will finish, but the trigger will stop checking for new events and invoking new runs. You can cancel runs to stop ones that are in progress, but currently is a separate gesture to just disable.